# How to set Server-Level Firewall on Azure VM?

Tags: azure, firewall, windows-firewall, windows-firewall-api

I found this page ["Create Firewall Rule"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dn505712.aspx), which suppose to show to set a VM Server-Level Firewall.

But, in the documentation the URL pattern includes "sqlserver": [https://management.core.windows.net:8443/{subscriptionId}/services/sqlservers/servers/{serverName}/firewallrules](https://management.core.windows.net:8443/%7BsubscriptionId%7D/services/sqlservers/servers/%7BserverName%7D/firewallrules)

1. Does it mean only SQLServers Firewall can be configured?
2. Is there another way to configure the Server-Level VM using the REST API?
3. Is there something similar to EC2 ["Instance Metadata and User Data"](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AESDG-chapter-instancedata.html) in Azure that I can use to inject my script on VM bootstrap so I can configure the Firewall from within?

**Edit**

I checked the built is Firewall is open and I can connect the service using "telnet XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX 5986"
This is the error I'm getting when I run:

```
>Test-WSMan XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX

Test-WSMan : <f:WSManFault xmlns:f="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wbem/wsman/1/wsmanfault" Code="2150859046"
Machine="WIN-HAPHAM5EH3M"><f:Message>WinRM cannot complete the operation. 
Verify that the specified computer name is valid, that the computer is accessible 
over the network, and that a firewall exception for the WinRM service is enabled and 
allows access from this computer. By default, the WinRM firewall exception for public 
profiles limits access to remote computers within the same local subnet. </f:Message></f:WSManFault>
At line:1 char:1
+ Test-WSMan XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:String) [Test-WSMan], InvalidOperationException
   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WsManError,Microsoft.WSMan.Management.TestWSManCommand
```

Answer (score 0):

1. The SQL Azure "firewall" is different from VM firewalls; it just provides a list of allowed IPs that can connect to the SQL Server database. It's the same option found in the Azure Portal.
2. There are also VM PowerShell CmdLets (that use the REST API) to control the endpoint ACLs - by default your VM is not internet accessible (besides a management port).

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-acl-powershell/

Comment: Yes i know about the endpoint, and i set it when i created the VM. My question is about the Server-level, meaning the windows internal builtin Firewall.

Answer (score 0):

1. The resource uri 
   *{subscriptionId}/services/sqlservers/servers/{serverName}/firewallrules* 
   refers to ACL's on SQL servers. This is available in this way only for SQL Azure.
   If you want the same functionality on VMs, you want to look at Network Security Groups (NSG). You can use these to limit access to virtual machines or subnets.
2. The REST apis used for management-plane operations, i.e. things taking place outside the VM. You can use it to change NSGs, but not the internal firewall. (unless you use it to kickoff some other mechanism that does that)
3. If you want to manage firewall rules inside the windows server VM, you can do this with either a script at deployment time, DSC, Group Policy, or powershell remoting (for example from azure automation, post deployment). For your question, you might want to look at something called a [Custom Script Extension.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/extensions-customscript) That helps you run a script inside the VM when you deploy it, for example to change firewall rules.